# VB.NET Sync Framework 2.1 doesn't work as expected

Tags: vb.net, frameworks, synchronization

I'm having some troubles with the Sync Framework 2.1 in VS 2017. I have one local database (SQL CE 4.0) and one distant (SQL SERVER 2012). I simply want to sync em so I've written :

```
    Dim serverConn As New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=DIVACOMWSSRV_USER_AIP;" &
            "Data Source=VSRV-DEV\MSSQLSERVER2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

    Dim scopeDesc As DbSyncScopeDescription = New DbSyncScopeDescription("AIP_USER")
    Dim tableDesc As DbSyncTableDescription = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("AIP_USER", serverConn)
    scopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc)
    Dim serverProvision As SqlSyncScopeProvisioning = New SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, scopeDesc)
    If Not serverProvision.ScopeExists("AIP_USER") Then
        serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip)
        serverProvision.Apply()
    End If


    Dim clientConn As SqlCeConnection = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Data\DWSU.sdf")
    scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope("AIP_USER", serverConn)

    Dim clientProvision As SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning = New SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, scopeDesc)
    If Not clientProvision.ScopeExists("AIP_USER") Then
        clientProvision.Apply()
    End If

    Dim myConnDist = serverConn
    Dim myConnLocal = clientConn

    Dim myLocalSP As New SqlCeSyncProvider("AIP_USER", myConnLocal)
    Dim myDistSP As New SqlSyncProvider("AIP_USER", myConnDist)

    Dim agent As New SyncOrchestrator
    agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload
    agent.LocalProvider = myLocalSP
    agent.RemoteProvider = myDistSP

    Dim syncOstats As SyncOperationStatistics = agent.Synchronize()
```

To keep it simple, I named my scope like my table.
The code works until

```
    Dim syncOstats As SyncOperationStatistics = agent.Synchronize()
```

Error :
-       $exception  {"Impossible de trouver une valeur à définir pour le paramètre de commande '@P_6'. Assurez-vous que les schémas des tables en cours de synchronisation sont cohérents, et que la configuration de cette étendue est correcte."} Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncException

So:

Unable to find a value to define for @P_6 parameter. Make sure tables schemas being sync are corrects and scopename is correct.

Except, there is NO 6 params in both tables but 5. I'm scratching my head and I checked both scopes, they are correct with only 5 parameters.

Has anyone encountered that exception?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : My bad, too quick..for an unknown reason, one column was missing in my distant table so that's why he asked for 6th param.